# Como melhorar o desempenho de um gerador de arquivos xls em minha aplicação Delphi 4 + SQL Server 2000?

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Implementei o procedimento abaixo em uma aplicação feita em Delphi 4, porém o tempo para gerar um arquivo xls com os dados do Dataset é de 55 segundos e o dataset tem aproximadamente 50 linhas. Alguma dica de como melhorar o desempenho?

```
procedure TfrmConsultaLeitos.ExpXLS(DataSet: TDataSet; Arq: string);
var
  ExcApp: OleVariant;
  i,l: integer;
begin
  Case MessageBox (Application.Handle, Pchar ('Aguarde! Será gerada uma planilha e esse processo demora alguns segundos, Deseja Continuar?'), 'Aplicação', MB_YESNO+MB_ICONINFORMATION+MB_DEFBUTTON2) of
  idYes:
  Begin
    dbgleitos.datasource.dataset.DisableControls;
    ExcApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    ExcApp.WorkBooks.Add;
    DataSet.First;
    l := 1;
    DataSet.First;
    Gauge.MinValue := 0;
    Gauge.MaxValue := DataSet.RecordCount;

    Gauge.Visible := true;

    //------------Define largura das células--------------------------------------
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 1].columnwidth := 17;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 2].columnwidth := 7;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 3].columnwidth := 5;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 4].columnwidth := 18;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 5].columnwidth := 50;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 6].columnwidth := 6;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 7].columnwidth := 40;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 8].columnwidth := 40;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 9].columnwidth := 5;
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    while not DataSet.EOF do
    begin
      for i := 0 to DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 do
      begin
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[l, i + 1] := DataSet.Fields[i].DisplayText;

        //------------Preenche o cabeçalho da planilha--------------------------------
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 1] :='Local';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 2] :='Quarto';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 3] :='Leito';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 4] :='Situação';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 5] :='Paciente';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 6] :='Idade';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 7] :='Visitante';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 8] :='Acompanhante';
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, 9] :='Sexo';
        //------------Preenche o cabeçalho da planilha--------------------------------

        //campo em negrito.
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[1, i + 1].Font.FontStyle := 'Negrito';

        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[l, i + 1].Borders.LineStyle := 1;

        //formato para numeros exemplos 1236,349 => 1.236,35
        ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].Sheets[1].Cells[l, i + 1].NumberFormat := '#.0';
      end;
      DataSet.Next;
      l := l + 1;

      Gauge.Progress := Gauge.Progress + 1;
    end;
    ExcApp.WorkBooks[1].SaveAs(Arq + '_'+ FormatDateTime('mm-dd-yyyy-hhnnss', now()));
    ExcApp.Visible := True;
  end;
  idNo:
       begin
            exit;   // Sai da Execução
       end;
   end;
   Gauge.Visible := false;
   dbgleitos.datasource.dataset.EnableControls;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largura das colunas, existe uma propriedade que deixa autosize (já fiz isso em VB6). Não entendi o lance de escrever o cabeçalho da coluna a cada iteração com o dataset, deveria fazer isso uma só vez e antes do While. Pra finalizar, a rotina toda rodando em Thread evitará o "travamento" na tela, dando um desempenho excelente e profissional ao seu aplicativo.

Comment: Olá, Marcelo. Tudo bem?
Implementei o que foi sugerido e houve redução significativa no tempo de 55s para aproximados 25s.
Obrigado.

Comment: Dá um like aí então. Gracias. rs

Comment: Eu infelizmente tive que tirar a formatação da planilha para ganhar em desempenho, o tempo para gerar o arquivo agora é de quatro segundos. Like dado!

Comment: Aplica a Thread como eu te falei. Será a solução definitiva. Vai poder até voltar com a formatação da planilha.

Answer (score 1):

A demora esta parecendo confusão da lógica, para cada REGISTRO do dataset ele percorre TODOS os Fields.

Imaginando que possua 50 registros e cada registro possua 25 colunas:

```
while not DataSet.EOF do
begin
  for i := 0 to DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 do
  begin
  ...
  end;

  DataSet.Next;
end;
```

Logo ele precisa realizar 50 * 25.

No caso o a intenção é obter o DisplayText dos field, então separe os 2 loops, pois não importa a quantidade de registros, os Fields serão SEMPRE os mesmos.

Edit:

Vale lembrar que no seu exemplo o:

```
while not DataSet.EOF do
begin
  ...
  DataSet.Next
end;
```

Não esta servindo para nada, utilize o `for` separado!

Comment: Olá, Júnior. Esse trecho do código serve para preencher as linhas do excel conforme query do dataset